# Android-Studio - AVD: Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vt-x, amd-phenom, android-studio

I'm having a machine with AMD Phenom II X4 955 running currently Windows 7 x64 SP1. Virtualization is activated under the Advanced CPU Settings in BIOS.

But when I want to add a device to the AVD it does show me this:
[image]

Does somebody has a similiar setup and can test this? Maybe it strictly needs VT-x and not AMD-V, but I don't find no related posts to this.

Comment: Some antivirus will block the use of virtualization tools by preemptively stealing vt-x (or AMD equivalent). Hyper-V will also steal the features. Make sure that all virtualization the OS might be doing is disabled and (temporarily) disable your AV to test that.

Comment: Since you have an AMD CPU, you'll have to run an ARM Image. To do this, go to `Android SDK Manager: Tools` -> `Android` -> `SDK Manager`, then chose any platform/package you want to download, expand it and select `ARM EABI v7a System Image` or `ARM 64 v8a System Image` then install. Alternatively, you could use the Android Emulator Genymotion, which works well with AMD and Intel.

Comment: Thank both of you guys.  But how am I supposed to add a stupid line break to my comment?  I'm having two spaces between every sentence and nothing happens.   Now three.    Now four....nothing happens. Why do people come here?

Comment: @dun You don't.  Edit your question if you need line breaks

Answer (score 2):

According to Android Documentation using Emulator your development system’s CPU should support VT-x. Without VT-x you can not use your cpu as virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else helps, the workaround is to use an alternative Android Emulator, e.g. [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).